# How to perform between date filter on SSAS MDX query

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I have the following script:

```
WITH 
MEMBER Measures.d AS SUM
   ( { [Measures].[Opening Debit]
         , [Measures].[Transaction Debit]}
    )
MEMBER Measures.c AS SUM
   ( { [Measures].[Opening Credit]
         , [Measures].[Transaction Credit]}
    ) 
MEMBER Measures.Balance AS 
  (
  (Measures.d) - (Measures.c)
  )
SELECT    
  {Measures.Balance} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
 {(
   [Trial Balance Tree].[Accthead].[Accthead],
   [Trial Balance Tree].[Accountgroup].[Accountgroup],
   [Trial Balance Tree].[Accountgroupdet].[Accountgroupdet],
   [Trial Balance Tree].[Analysis Group].[Analysis Group],
   [Trial Balance Tree].[Account Tree ID].[Account Tree ID],
   [Trial Balance Tree].[Vchrdate].[Vchrdate],
   [Calender 1].[Thisyear].[thisyear],
 {[Trial Balance Tree].[BranchID].[BranchID].[1],
  [Trial Balance Tree].[BranchID].[BranchID].[2]}
 )}
ON ROWS
from [TrialBalance]
where
(
[Trial Balance Tree].[Date].[Date].[20140101]:[Trial Balance Tree].[Date].[Date].[20141231]
)
```

I want to filter Date between `01/01/2014` and `31/12/2014`.Please any one suggest me how to do it?

Comment: putting code [Trial Balance Tree].[Date].[Date].&[20140101]:[Trial Balance Tree].[Date].[Date].&[20141231]  in on Rows  throws error : The '20140101' string cannot be converted to the date type

Comment: is this querying a new cube? i.e. could there be problems inside the cube?

Comment: Does your Date dimension have a date-type column as its key column?  This makes it very difficult to match on the dimension key.  I've tried adjusting the language setting on my server from US to UK, but SSAS still presents the key value as "m/d/yy", and it's still impossible to match these key values with MDX like this: [Date].[5/9/16] for 5th May.  Sadly, I think that SSAS just handles date-types horribly.  If you can't change the dimension to use e.g. a numeric yyyymmdd key, try adding a Name Column in the dimension and matching on that in your MDX.

Comment: Date type is ok to use as primary key in a pure relational database but keys for a cube are better as yyyymmdd - I think this is pretty standard. If you're not using this then changing to this system should be high up in your list of tasks.

Comment: While creating Trial Balance Tree dimension I have to given Date,Vchrdate as a key columns along with AccountTreeID because of errors occurred if I do not do so. Next I also tried by changing Date properties type from regular to date.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly more modern syntax:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].d AS 
  [Measures].[Opening Debit] +  [Measures].[Transaction Debit]
MEMBER [Measures].c AS
  [Measures].[Opening Credit] + [Measures].[Transaction Credit]
MEMBER [Measures].Balance AS 
  [Measures].d - [Measures].c
SELECT    
  [Measures].Balance ON 0,
NON EMPTY
    [Trial Balance Tree].[Accthead].[Accthead]
  * [Trial Balance Tree].[Accountgroup].[Accountgroup]
  * [Trial Balance Tree].[Accountgroupdet].[Accountgroupdet]
  * [Trial Balance Tree].[Analysis Group].[Analysis Group]
  * [Trial Balance Tree].[Account Tree ID].[Account Tree ID]
  * [Trial Balance Tree].[Vchrdate].[Vchrdate]
  * [Calender 1].[Thisyear].[thisyear]
  * {
     [Trial Balance Tree].[BranchID].[BranchID].[1],
     [Trial Balance Tree].[BranchID].[BranchID].[2]
    }
  * {
     [Trial Balance Tree].[Date].[Date].&[20140101]  
    :[Trial Balance Tree].[Date].[Date].&[20141231]
    }
ON 1
FROM [TrialBalance];
```

I've included the ampersand, in front of `[20140101]` and `[20141231]` as they look like keys to me rather than captions.

Comment: @AmitBhatt apologies - I've left in a comma after `[Calender 1].[Thisyear].[thisyear]` that is just infront of `{`

Comment: While creating Trial Balance Tree dimension I have to given Date,Vchrdate as a key columns along with AccountTreeID because of errors occurred if I do not do so. Next I also tried by changing Date properties type from regular to date.